# Load dependencies in Vscode preview

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, axios

I'm working in VSCode with some Vue components that I copy/paste into my company's CMS (long story). I have a single file for each component (HTML with inline CSS and some Vue and Axios) that appears on the final webpage which has dependencies in the head. There's often trial and error to test my endpoints, text formatting, etc. so I would like to test before deploying to my site with a tool like VSCode. Is there a way to tell VSCode to load the Vue and Axios frameworks rather than include them at the top of each component file? I can test each piece individually but not together.

As you can see, I may also just be missing some major concepts in web development and/or VSCode features.

Comment: I think you can use the [`unplugin-auto-import`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unplugin-auto-import) tool in order to manage things how you want. But it's a little tricky to handle `axios` with this plugin. Hope you find the way by try and error

Comment: Also try to create `unit` and `e2e` testing for each component to avoid manual testing...